# Python, NLP - finding the top document containing given list of words

Tags: python, nlp

I am new to learning NLP. I am trying to do an exercise of finding the best matching resume.

For example, I have a list of skills that I am looking for like ['java', 'python', 'SQL', 'API', ...], and a set of documents. I want to create a model to find the document that is the best match with these skills. Similar to resume matching.

I started with this tutorial - [Extracting words from pdf](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-convert-pdfs-into-searchable-key-words-with-python-85aab86c544f) as a reference

I was able to extract the text from pdf, remove stop words, perform lemmatization, compute the number of times these keywords appear in each document and I am not sure how to go head from here.

Could anyone provide me with what the next steps should be? Any tutorials or references would be helpful as well.

Comment: Find matching is a very subjective goal. The first thing I would think about is to define what do you mean by a match, or a method to rank resumes based on the information you have found. For example, one way of ranking is by the total number of times any word in your list showed up in the resume. Furthermore, you can consider the variaty of words that showed up as well (i.e. you don't want anyone who showed only python 100 times in their resume).

Comment: @TYZ, I agree completely – and I think you mean it's a very "subjective" goal. Lots of ways to define a good match.

Comment: @blacksite LOL my bad, just fixed it. Forgive my poor English, I never get this correct.

Comment: @TYZ I agree with you as well. Here I am looking for documents that have largest intersection with the skillset and if documents have same intersection but in few, the words appear multiple times then that should be given more preference.

Answer (score 1):

if you assume that "the best matching", is the resume with the "largest intersection" with the set skills, then you would have (python):

```
import numpy as np
D=[["I","know","python"],["I","know","java"]] # list of Documents
skils=["java"] # list of skils
I=[len(list(set(skils) & set(d))) for d in D]
R = sorted(range(len(I)), key=lambda k: I[k]) # rank of intersection with the skillset
best_resume=R[0]
print (R)
```

I hope it can be useful. good luck.

Comment: Here I am looking for documents that have the largest intersection with the skillset and if documents have the same intersection but in few, the words appear multiple times then that should be given more preference.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you might be interested in a rank based on the intersection... I've updated the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the vector similarity approach.

The best matching resume is the similarity between the query (qualification keywords) and the texts. You can use [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) or [sbert](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html) -which I prefer most- to collect the top n best results.

```
corpus_embeddings = model.encode(YOUR_CV_TEXT, convert_to_tensor=True)
query_1=['java python SQL']

for query in query_1:
    query_embedding = model.encode(query_1, convert_to_tensor=True)

    cos_scores = util.cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=5)

    print("\n\n======================\n\n")
    print("Query:", query)
    print("\nTop 5 most similar sentences in corpus:")

    for score, idx in zip(top_results[0], top_results[1]):
        print(par_list[idx], "(Score: {:.4f})".format(score))
```

For more you can deep dive into: [Semantic Search](https://towardsdatascience.com/semantic-search-73fa1177548f)